# How to setup a working bootstrap carousel within a for loop?

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap, jinja2

I'm trying to make a carousel in a flask app that displays all images from a database through a loop, I have found similar questions but the answers don't work for me.

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for raffle in query %}

          <div class="carousel-item {% if loop.index == 1 %} active {% endif %}" id="slide{{ loop.index }}">
            <img src="{{ raffle.IMAGES }}">
          </div>

   {% endfor %}
 </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#pageCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bg-primary" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#pageCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon bg-primary" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

The first image in the loop is displayed as it should but the slide keys don't do anything. How can I make all the images in the loop work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `href` attribute of the `a` elements of the controls should have the `id` of the outer carousel `div`:

```
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" ...
```

Same goes for the "next" control.